Issues with running BIND9 on WSL2 Ubuntu 22.04 Instance on Windows 11
I am running BIND9 on WSL Ubuntu 22.04 with some local domain names which are intended to resolve back to the same system's IP address.
Running the WSL in NAT mode requires port forwarding for services running inside WSL but UDP forwarding is not natively supported in Windows (through netsh)
If I provide the WSL IP as a DNS server to the windows host machine, it is able to query against the BIND9 DNS Server
But other systems in the LAN cannot since the queries are not being forwarded to the system
So I tried to use mirrored networking mode but then the Windows host machine needs to be configured with its own IP address as the DNS Server to query ? It is unable to query at its IP address, or its own loopback 127.0.0.1#53 address either.
